# Obscure Looping Error in Theano

Tags: python, theano

I am trying to simulate a repeat-until loop in Theano:

```
def method_a(arguments):
    ...
    return result, theano.scan.until(t.eq(a,b))
```

I encountered the following strange behaviour. Let `b` be a constant. Whenever `a` is a constant, everything works fine. However, when `a` is a scalar, I get an error related to optimisation:

```
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): SeqOptimizer apply <theano.gof.opt.EquilibriumOptimizer object at 0x110d0d8d0>
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 196, in apply
    sub_prof = optimizer.optimize(fgraph)
  File "[...]/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 82, in optimize
    ret = self.apply(fgraph, *args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1665, in apply
    gopt.apply(fgraph)
  File "[...]/python2.7/site-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_opt.py", line 1300, in apply
    if self.belongs_to_set(nd, subset):
  File "[...]/python2.7/site-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_opt.py", line 1286, in belongs_to_set
    rep.op.inputs)
  File "[...]/python2.7/site-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_utils.py", line 452, in equal_computations
    dx.type.dtype == dy.type.dtype and
AttributeError: 'NoneTypeT' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I'd appreciate if someone could help me understand the error. I'm assuming the `AttributeError` doesn't refer to `a` or `b`, because I can print their `dtype` and see that they do have one. Other than that, I can't make any sense out of it.

[Edit] This is not a fatal error. The code runs normally and the process finishes with exit code 0. It looks like Theano is trying to optimise the graph and fails to do so, which doesn't really impact the program.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: I edited the question so that it contains the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback indicate that in the function equal_compuations(), we didn't cover all case, when doing some comparison.

I have a PR with a fix for it here:

```
https://github.com/Theano/Theano/pull/1928
```

thanks for the report.

Your [edit] section, indicate me that you cut some of the errors message. If this happear during optimization with a warning, it mean an optimization was just skipped. It is possible that the optimization just don't apply, but it could be possible that with the fix, now the optimization apply. If that is the case, there could be some speed up with the fix.

Comment: This PR is now merged in the development version of Theano.